# Python script running installer.exe without user interaction

Tags: python

I am "translating" powershell scripts in to python, and I am having problems when it comes to run a installer.exe because it has to be automatic and with 0 interaction from the user. They just have to run the script and it installs both program and Microsoft Visual C++ versions. I mean, run, install and close on the background.

On powershell, it was so simple like doing this:

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "$pwd\VC\vcredist2013_x64.exe" -ArgumentList "/passive /norestart" -PassThru | Out-Null
```

On python, i tried this and more:

```
import subprocess

def startProgram():
    SW_HIDE = 0
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    VC13=subprocess.Popen(r'vcredist2013_x64.exe', startupinfo=info)
    VC13.wait()
startProgram()
```

But they are not working, the wizard still pops up.

Comment: At least, you are not passing the arguments: `/passive /norestart`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the subprocess.run method instead, with the stdout and stderr parameters redirected to subprocess.DEVNULL. The /passive and /norestart arguments can be passed using the args parameter.

Here's an updated code snippet:

```
import subprocess

def startProgram():
    subprocess.run(["vcredist2013_x64.exe", "/passive", "/norestart"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

startProgram()
```

Comment: It did not work as intended, because the window still pops up, but at least the installation is automatic, thank you so much!!